# Unable to deploy Dell PowerEdge R750s iDrac using MaaS

Tags: dell, power-management, ipmi

I have installed MaaS 3.1.0 to manage 5 Dell PowerEdge R750 servers, iDrac 5.00.10.10. I'm able to commission and test the servers fine, all test passing, but when I get to the Deployment, it fails with the error in logs:

`Failed to power on node - Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Device busy while performing power action. MAAS performed several retries. Please wait and try again.`

I've tried scores of times, manually inputting the IPMI user/password, thinking that might be the issue, but I know using ipmitool with the same credentials, it works. Also, all the actions during commission and test are doing the same things that Deploy would require (correct?)

I'm all out of ideas, not sure what else to try. I'm hoping there are others with Dell servers who may have encountered this found a way of getting past it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading about Redfish, I decided to give that a try. It's enabled by default in the iDrac. I ensured credentials for a `maas` user worked, changed to redfish, and was able to fully deploy all machines.